# Adding text to beginning of Object property value

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

Hi there I am adding the string 'a ' to the beginning of the value of `name`. I have also added a condition where if the value of `name.length === 3`, then add the string `'a '` but it is only returning the objects that get changed and only the `name` property.

```js
var values1 = [
  {
    name: 'dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
  {
    name: 'cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer',
  },
  {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
];

let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
  if (values1[i]['name'].length == 3) {
    array.push({ name: 'a ' + values1[i]['name'] });
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

This is the result I would like to return.

```
[
  {
    name: 'a dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
  {
    name: 'a cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer',
  },
  {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
];
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you mean 'Result in Terminal' is the result you would like to achieve?

Comment: I am not the best at explaining, but if you look at the console.logged result, its essentially what I want

Comment: You're actually quite close, but review if this line makes sense: `array.push({ name: 'a ' + values1[i]['name'] });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close, but instead of adding a name key (`push()`) you want to reassign the value of the `name` field.

```js
var values1 = [
  {
    name: 'dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
  {
    name: 'cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer',
  },
  {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
  if (values1[i]['name'].length == 3) {
    values1[i]['name'] = 'a ' + values1[i]['name'];
  }
}

console.log(values1)
```

I modified the existing array rather than adding a new one. I don't think it's dangerous as we are updating a primitive.

Comment: This mutates the array in place, which it looks like the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: I do mention that ('modified the existing array'), but it wasn't mentioned in the post, so I assumed it was just because they didn't see how to mutate it in place. If that's a requirement it's a fairly easy change.

edit: I think your answer is overall better due to the explanation, but I wanted to provide one as well to help OP see where they went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `name` property in the callback.

```js
var values1 = [
  { name: 'dog', surname: 'good', skills: 'programming' },
  { name: 'cat', surname: 'soft', skills: 'engineer' },
  { name: 'elephant', surname: 'big', skills: 'programming' },
];

const result = values1.map(({ name, ...rest }) => 
  ({ name: (name.length === 3 ? `a ${name}` : name), ...rest }));

console.log(result);
```

But to make your code work you simply need to be sure to push the whole object regardless of whether the name is changed or not. Here creating a copy of the object using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) updating the `name` if needed, then pushing the copy to the array.

```js
var values1 = [
  {
    name: 'dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
  {
    name: 'cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer',
  },
  {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming',
  },
];

let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
  const obj = Object.assign({}, values1[i]);

  if (obj['name'].length === 3) {
    obj.name = 'a ' + obj['name'];
  }

  array.push(obj);
}

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid ...rest as this code is used at a bigger scale. I just asked this question for a simple reasons

Comment: The second example doesn't use `...rest` but it does clone the objects using spread.